# Disable selection when (accidentally) clicking on empty space (with CSS)

Tags: html, css, select, text

I have the following annoying problem: When clicking multiple times on empty spaces in my website, it selects entire rows and paragraphs, [as demonstrated by this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bb9wu5Lz/1).

But since there is no text under the cursor (e.g. the empty green region), I don't even understand why it would want to select anything in the first place.

Simply put: If I click on text, I want default selection behavior, but if I do not click on text, it should not select anything. Is that possible?

Reference HTML code:

```
<div>
    <span>Clicks:</span> <input id="clicks" value="0"></input>

    <div style="background-color:LightGreen"
        onclick="$('#clicks').val(parseInt($('#clicks').val()) + 1);"><span class="hard">CLICK THE GREEN AND CLICK IT HARD!</span>
    <br/>
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS5lQfEXNPKzMGZRHUQJJJj97NFoi1Q4iZ_dT1GK9lrYsjrgd7i5XWsrTA"></img>
       <div style="width: 100%; display:inline-block"><span>more text</span></div>
    </div>
    <span>even more text</span>

    <p id="log"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Eagerly awaiting the `:accident` CSS selector..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can solve this with [CSS' `user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select).

[Try out the solution in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bb9wu5Lz/4/).

We first disable overall text-selection, like so:

```
/**
 * Disallow selection for the entire site.
 */
body {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */ 
}
```

And then, we take a good look at the set of [all HTML elements](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/), and [white-list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) all text-only elements, like so:

```
/**
 * White-list all of HTML5's "pure text" elements.
 * @see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/
 */
 a, abbr, address, b, bdi, bdo, blockquote, br, button, caption, center, 
 cite, code, col, dd, del, dfn, dt, em, figcaption, footer, h1, h2, h3, h4, 
 h5, h6, i,  input, ins, kbd, label, legend, mark, output, p, pre, q, rp, rt, 
 ruby, s,  samp, small, span, strike, strong, sub, summary, sup, td, textarea, 
 th, time,  title, tt, u, var {
    -webkit-user-select: text; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
    -moz-user-select: text; /* mozilla browsers */
    -khtml-user-select: text; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
    -ms-user-select: text; /* IE10+ */
 }
```

This way, the user can still select text, but will not accidentally select empty spaces. If you find any text that is not selectable, just wrap it in a `<span>`.

Comment: You just asked a question and you just answered it? why?

Comment: @VangelTzo Let me refer you to [the official SO blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/): "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged." -  In my case, I heard of this problem when talking to a friend many months ago, and today I also came across this problem and I was able to solve it. My friend thought, it was a good solution. I am guessing, many other people have a similar problem...

Comment: I didn't knew about that, you are free to post it since it's valid to SO rules ;)

Comment: @VangelTzo I get it - A lot of people (judging from the amount of upvotes of your comment) are not happy with people doing this because they think, it's some sort of rep-farming. Seeing how this question is actually a duplicate (as it turns out; I did not know that!), I agree that things look fishy here. :P

Comment: @Domi since this question has been asked before, I suggest you flag this question for moderator's attention, and request a merge. This will move your answer to the canonical question, so that it can be seen :)

Comment: But you can ctrl+a and highlight the content right..? how to prevent that..?

Comment: @PabodhaWimalasuriya I would suggest using a library like [Hotkeys.js](https://github.com/jaywcjlove/hotkeys), add an event handler and `preventDefault()` :)